# How come MCPE is taking up 3.5 GB on my IPod?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am on aquatic update and only have 25 worlds but it's taking up 3.5 GB! I want to delete it so I can get my space back and redownload but I fear that I'll lose my worlds!! What do I do?

Comment: As of MCPE 0.9 and later, world sizes are infinite.  The further you walk, the larger the world sizes are.  That's where all your space are going.

Answer (score 1):

0kay so to do this, if you have icloud, unistalling and reinstalling will do no harm to your worlds. Also 25 worlds is alot for 1 app. Go and delete some of those worlds you don't use.